# Como executar chamada procedure do banco com parametro com JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, jpa-2.0, spring-jpa

Como faço para executar a chamada de uma Stored Procedure do banco
Tenho o seguinte procedimento armazenado no banco, e desejo executar sua chamada passando o parâmetro `projId`, usando JPA para pegar o custo total da entidade *Projeto*

[image: Stored Procedure]

Banco: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Tentou usar `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`?

Comment: Essa chamada não e para as procedure declaradas na classe?